Postman POST request to create user failing
I'm trying to send a POST request to the /api/users endpoint in Postman, but I'm getting a "400 Bad Request" error. Here's the request details:
Method: POST
URL: http://localhost:3000/api/users
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json Body:
I expect the request to create a new user, but instead, I'm getting this error:
I've checked my network connection and verified that the server is running. I'm using Postman version 11.13.1 on windows. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
Operating System: Windows 11
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400F @ 2.60GHz
Postman Version: [Specify the version of Postman you're using]
API Endpoint: http://localhost:3000/api/users
Request Method: POST
Postman network error status screenshot 
Login html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cable Shopy Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo">Cable Shopy Login</h1>
    <form id="login-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        <span class="toggle-password"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
        <label for="remember-me">Remember Me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>
    <div id="error-message"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Login CSS Code
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f3efea;
  }
  
  .container {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 400px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  .form-group label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  .form-group input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  .toggle-password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .toggle-password i {
    color: #ccc;
  }
  
  .form-group input:focus,
  .toggle-password i:hover {
    color: #007bff;
  }
  
  #remember-me {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
  button[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #ec671a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #88dd42;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  #error-message {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  /* Font Awesome (optional, for the eye icon) */
  @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css");

Login js code
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Login() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Basic validation
    if (username.trim() === '' || password.trim() === '') {
      setErrorMessage('Please enter username and password.');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data.success) {
        // Login successful
        console.log('Login successful!');
      } else {
        setErrorMessage(data.message || 'Login failed.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setErrorMessage('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    
    }
  };

  const handleTogglePassword = () => {
    setShowPassword((prevShowPassword) => !prevShowPassword);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="logo">Cable Shopy Login</h1>
      <form id="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            name="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            id="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
          <span className="toggle-password" onClick={handleTogglePassword}>
            <i className={showPassword ? 'fas fa-eye-slash' : 'fas fa-eye'} />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />
          <label htmlFor="remember-me">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
      </form>
      {errorMessage && <p className="error-message">{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default Login;

Server.js code
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cableshopy');

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});

db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});


User.js code
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;


Api.js code
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User');

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ username });
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid username or password' });
  }
  if (!(await user.comparePassword(password))) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid username or password' });
  }
  res.json({ success: true, message: 'Login successful' });
});

module.exports = router;

I expected the POST request to be successful and a new user to be created in the database.

There is not any /user api instead of user you need to hit  /login api .  /api/login

can you please help me  to fix this  error?

http://localhost:3000/api/login Yoy need to hit this url in Postman and make sure you hit POST req

Still I'm facing same issue

The error message you're encountering, a 400 Bad Request, suggests that there is an issue with the request body you are sending to the server. Specifically, it indicates that the server could not process the request due to invalid syntax, likely because the format or data in the request body doesn't match what the server expects.
400 status code indicate user error
Bad Request message indicate your request body is not matching with requirement.
please debug username, password you are getting from request.body, is this same as you are entering in login form
console.log("Username:", username);
console.log("Password:", password);
